# Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection when returning an entity object from delete method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While I was practicing to implement `@OneToMany` bididrectional association I got stuck in implementing delete operation for a `User` entity, I receive this warning - `Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session` 
 
So, I have two entities as follows :

##### User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id ;

    private String username ;
    private String password ;
    private String email ;
    private String firstname ;
    private String lastname ;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user" ,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>() ;

    // getters and setters
}
```

##### Playlist Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "playlist")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property = "id")
public class Playlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // getters and setters

}
```

##### UserController Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class userController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService ;

    // ... other controller mappings

    @PostMapping("")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User reqUser){
        return userService.createUser(reqUser) ;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userID}")
    public User removeUser (@PathVariable Long userID) {
        return userService.removeUser(userID) ;
    }
}
```

##### removeUser method in UserService Class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo ;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List <User> users = new ArrayList<>() ;
        userRepo.findAll().forEach(users::add);
        return users ;
    }

    public User createUser(User reqUser) {
        User newUser = new User() ;
        newUser.setUsername(reqUser.getUsername());
        newUser.setEmail(reqUser.getEmail());
        newUser.setPassword(reqUser.getPassword());
        newUser.setFirstname(reqUser.getFirstname());
        newUser.setLastname(reqUser.getLastname());

        // adding playlists
        reqUser.getPlaylists().forEach( playlist -> {
            newUser.addPlaylist(playlist);
        });

        userRepo.save(newUser) ;

        return newUser ;
    }
    
    public User removeUser(Long userID) {

        // check if user exists
        User user = userRepo.findById(userID).orElseThrow(
                () -> new EntityNotFoundException("User doesn't exists with userID " + userID)
        );

        userRepo.deleteById(userID) ;
        return user ;
    }
}
```

The Get request for user fetches me this response:

```
{
    "id": 20,
    "username": "poodie",
    "password": "randomPasswrod",
    "email": null,
    "firstname": "Raj",
    "lastname": "Bhushan",
    "playlists": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "name": "playlist-01",
            "description": "first playlist",
            "user": 20,
            "songs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "playlist-02",
            "description": "first playlist",
            "user": 20,
            "songs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Sadly, when I want to delete this same User, **even though it gets deleted but I get this error in POSTMAN**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-02T14:39:45.433+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/users/20"
}
```

Below you can see the warning received in stack trace :

```
2023-04-02 20:09:45.418  WARN 26500 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter
.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml
.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.rudra.musicStreaming
.models.User["playlists"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.rudra.musicStreaming.models.Playlist["songs"])]
```

**Although this user gets deleted from DB, but leaves this warning in the stack trace. How can I get rid of this problem (`Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection, could not initialize proxy - no Session`) and what is the cause of this issue ?**

Note : When I modify the delete method to not return any `User` object, everything works fine but when I try to return `User` entity's object while performing delete operation (as shown in the code shared above) this warning occurs within the stack trace.

Comment: Delete endpoint should return nothing by convention. You can't return user just deleted. Why should you?

Comment: This is not clear do you want to fix a Lazy initialization exception or awoid it?

Comment: @RomanC whichever is the best option, but I think I would love to understand both of them fixing as well as avoiding it. Also I am not able to understand why every other endpoint such as POST/GET/PUT requests works fine, but when I try to return object from DELETE endpoint only then why do I get this exception ?

Comment: Why do you need it? These objects should be removed as well before you delete a user.

Comment: @RomanC most likely in real project I won't use it, but since learning I would like to know the actual problem behind this, as well as also the workaround to fix this.

Comment: Fixing is easy if you understand what I have written in the answer below.

Comment: thnx for your answer, I was also somewhat naively thinking in a similar direction

Comment: @RomanC I now understand what I m doing is ideally wrong, but I would like to know if there is no other way out to have what I m trying to achieve, i.e. return an object from DELETE endpoint and also don't receive this exception ?

Comment: The entity object you return no longer in the db, nor in the session, and also have orphans removed option. What a list you want to get? You said than GET/POST/PUT methods works but you didn't post a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`LazyInitializationException`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html):

> Indicates an attempt to access unfetched data outside the context of an open stateful Session.
> For example, this exception occurs when an uninitialized proxy or collection is accessed after the session was closed.

is coming because you use a proxy object returned by the repository. The proxy is trying to initialize a collection associated with that object when you access it. But it fails to initialize a collection because this object is no longer in the session since it was removed.